# object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri' - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-serializer

I am trying to view a url in my api (using Django Rest Framework), but I get the following error:

```
'Follow' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'
```

I'm not sure what this means, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  451.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  448.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get
  199.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  44.             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  618.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  213.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  568.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  435.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in to_representation
  1330.         return method(value)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/src/accounts/serializers.py" in get_supporting
  124.         return serializer.data
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  618.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  213.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  568.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  435.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in to_representation
  264.             return self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/src/accounts/serializers.py" in get_url
  34.                        request=request, format=format)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in reverse
  26.     return _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
File "/Users/jphalis/Desktop/oby/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in _reverse
  39.         return request.build_absolute_uri(url)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api2/follows/
Exception Value: 'Follow' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'
```

I'm assuming it's referring to my model, so here's that as well:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self',
                                       related_name='following',
                                       symmetrical=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

MyUser.profile = property(lambda u: Follow.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**- - EDIT:**

***serializers.py:***

```
class FollowSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', read_only=True)
    supporters = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    supporting = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_supporters(self, instance):
        queryset = Follow.objects.filter(following__pk=instance.pk)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(queryset,
                                           context={"request": instance},
                                           many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_supporting(self, instance):
        queryset = Follow.objects.filter(followers__pk=instance.pk)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(queryset,
                                           context={"request": instance},
                                           many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = [
            'username',
            'supporters',
            'supporting',
        ]

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    account_url = UserProfileUrlField("user_profile_detail_api")
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'account_url',
            'username',
        ]
```

**ListAPIView:**

```
class FollowListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    queryset = Follow.objects.all()
```

Comment: Can you share your serializers and routers as well?  It looks like something is going on in your 'get_url' method there.

Comment: @bwarren2 Added my serializer. I don't have a router setup for it, only a ListAPIView that feeds directly off of the serializer.

Comment: It looks like you are passing the model instance in place of the request variable via `"request": instance`.  Why are you doing that?  

You might post UserProfileSerializer as well.

Comment: @bwarren2 I posted it below the `FollowSerializer`. I was following a tutorial and tried to mimic the results. Is there a better way to retrieve the data? Maybe setup a separate serializer for just that instance?

Comment: Can you post your ListAPIView?

Comment: @bwarren2 I posted the ListAPIView for `Follow`. `UserProfile` is the exact same, but changing the model from `Follow` to `UserProfile` and the serializer class where appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you are passing a model instance rather than the originating request in your serializer.

I suspect you need to instead pass the request via the context in the first serializer call (in your ListAPIView) then access it via self.context in your serializer class.  [See here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).  This will let you use the request data to build the uri (and avoid the "No attribute" error you have right now, because you will be passing the kind of object that method expects).

This involves overriding the methods declared [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3e1687282ba39b0166b7c17e39cdd3a2be7e2bc3/rest_framework/generics.py#L195-L201) and [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3e1687282ba39b0166b7c17e39cdd3a2be7e2bc3/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35-L48) in your ListAPIView.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the traceback, it seems you are doing something wrong in the `get_url()` function which you have overridden in your `serializers.py`.

According to [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#advanced-hyperlinked-fields),

> This method should return the URL that corresponds to the given
>   object.

Basic signature of DRF reverse() function:

```
def reverse(viewname, args=None, kwargs=None, request=None, format=None, **extra):
```

You must pass the proper values for the arguments as defined in `reverse()`. The error might be arising due to incorrect values being sent to `reverse()` function.